# Combine two circuits in Multisim

Tags: simulation, output, input, multisim

I have two circuits, two separate simulations in Multisim, which work fine until I try to combine them.
I tried a common ground, on-page connectors, added the voltage follower, but that didn't help.

What confuses me even more is that these two circuits do not work if they are placed on the same page.

[image]

Edited: sometimes it runes for ~0.1s and then stopped with the Simulation Error. But even in this short time it does not behave as I expect.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the error? You cut out the one thing that could lead to an answer. Check for duplicate node names, or duplicate reference designators (I don't see any but, ...).

Comment: @a-concerned-citizen, the Simulation Error sais: "A simulation error has occurred. Would you like to run the Convergence Assistant to attempt to resolve this problem automatically?"
I ran. But Convergence Assistant failed to resolve convergence issue: "Convergence Assistant completed unsuccessfully."

Comment: Did you copy and paste one into the other? If you did, you might try starting with the more complicated one, making sure it works, then editing it to add the other circuit one component at a time, it's only 8 components so it shouldn't take long. Then try the simulation again. That should eliminate the possibility of duplicate components or nodes that you might get with copy and paste.

Comment: @godjihyo, I did exactly what you suggested. I got the correct first pulse that I was supposed to get. But in 0.1s it stopped with the Simulation Error again.